# Calculating scroll length in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

In the WPF datagrid, there's the ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged event.  When I put a breakpoint at the method, I get some random float numbers.  Are these pixels?

I'm basically trying to calculate how far I am moving along the whole horizontal scale of the DataGrid so I can update another custom plot chart in its own scale.  But I'm not sure what the HorizontalChange and HorizontalOffset numbers are.  Thanks.

Comment: They are likely normalized numbers, not pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the value returned is device independent pixels.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.horizontaloffset.aspx

**

> A positive HorizontalOffset value corresponds to the content being
>   offset to the left. Valid values are between zero and the ExtentWidth
>   minus the ViewportWidth. The returned value is described in Device
>   Independent Pixels.

**